# How to disable writes on temporary returned by getter?

Tags: c++

I have a getter which returns a temporary object, copy of the internal object.

Something like the following:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    QString name() {return m_name;}
    void setName(const QString &name);
private:
    QString m_name;
}
```

The intended usage of the setter/getter is to get the data through `name()` and set the data through `setName()`.

But sometimes, incorrectly, I tend to do the following:

```
name().clear();
```

Or some other modification directly to the getter's return.

NOTE that the intention with the above line (and with similar modifications) is to clear the name in `Foo`, not the temporary variable, so the line above compiles correctly, but behaves incorrectly, since it will clear the temporary, not Foo's member.

How can I disable such an incorrect usage, and get an error at compile time?

Note that I may have both, third-party types (which I cannot modify, like std::string, or the QString above) and custom types (which I can modify for this).

Edit:

Note that overloading with `const`, `&`, `&&` or similar are not useful, since I may have something like:

```
Foo foo;
foo.name().clear();
```

Which no matter what overload you choose, it will always compile fine.

Also, all the modifications to the internal member must go through `setName()`, since it will apply some logic and notify some other objects, so any modification not made through the interface must be avoided. This prevents the getter returning by non-const reference to allow the above usage or make the private member as public.

Comment: Since `name` returns the string by *value* it returns a *copy* of the string. Any modifications made to it will be made on the copy only, the `m_name` member will stay unmodified. So the code you show already does what you want.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No, I don't want to modify the temporary "thinking" that I am modifying the `Foo` object. I want `name().clear()` to fail, since what I want to clear is the name in Foo, not the temporary.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have edited the question, trying to clarify the problem

Comment: IMHO your are takling the issue from the wrong side. The interface of Foo is perfectly reasonable, it is the client code of it that should it right, surely accidental modifcation of a temporary object can be spotted in the unit tests.

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi yes, but a correct interface also should try to enforce correct usage, which in this case it fails to do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe try

```
const QString name() const {return m_name;}
```

This will prevent direct use of:

```
foo.name().clear();
```

Please also note, as underlined in the comments, that as the returned QString is a **copy**, `foo.name().clear();` won't modify `foo.m_name`. But yes, a quick read of the code can be confusing.

---

EDIT extra reads: [when-use-const-3-return-types](https://www.sandordargo.com/blog/2020/11/18/when-use-const-3-return-types)

---

A more involved solution, inspired by [thoughts-about-getters-and-setters](https://cpp-rendering.io/thoughts-about-getters-and-setters-in-c/), would be

```
class Foo {
   
  public:
    ... 

    const QString& name() const & {return m_name;}   
    QString name() && {return std::move(m_name);}

  private:
    QString m_name;         
};
```

Please also note that the blog post encourages a simple solution like this one:

```
class Foo {
  ... 
  public
    QString name;         
};
```

This is an economical and viable solution when you do not have to enforce some **invariant** or do some **other actions** in the 'setter' method.

Comment: const QString name() const {return m_name; }

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi opss, thanks for pointing out my typo :)

Comment: It should be noted that having a `const` return type only makes sense in the specific case of chained function calls or direct manipulation of the returned object. The caller can still assign to a non-const object and modify that (and using `auto` type-deduction will drop the `const` qualifier which might be surprising to some). Also, since the returned value is `const` then the function might as well return a `const` *reference*.

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi with that you can't observe the `name` of a mutable `Foo`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude “The caller can still assign to a non-const object and modify that.” — Yes, and that operation is perfectly sensible, and *should* be supported. What issue do you see?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think it's just important to mention it, since I've seen beginners be confused by that concept. Especially when using `auto` type-deduction.

Comment: I didn't know that the return types could be const when returning by value. This is nice, since it throws a compile time error, and prevents direct modification of the internal value, as in the Caleth answer. Also, I like returning it by value instead of reference, since I want them to be different objects.

Comment: Can you expand a bit more on the edit with the & and &&?

Comment: @LoPiTaL you can read the blog I cite in my answer this is very instructive

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude returning by const val will break the move sematnics, so from C++11 and further that is considered a bad practice.

Comment: @LoPiTaL in short, adding a `&` after the method returning the const reference prevents C++ from using this method when you have `foo` by value. This avoid creation of dangling references. But I encourage you to read the blog post where you will find a more comprehensive answer.

Comment: @LoPiTaL you can also check Josuttis's C++ Move Semantics, he discusses cases like that in the detail.

Comment: Ok, I have read it. It is not useful for my usecase, since I may have `Foo foo; foo.name().clear()`, and in this case I still want to disable the usage.

Comment: @LoPiTaL the just return by const ref, it seems the easiest way to me.

Comment: About the edit, the setter does some logic, so it must not be bypassed. That is the whole point of setters/getters :)

Comment: @LoPiTaL thanks for the clarification :). This was just in case as we sometimes forget the simplest solutions

Comment: One final question, with the return by const-value, the move semantics are broken. This is OK, since the foo class will almost never be used as rvalue. But does the const-value return prevent return copy ellision optimization? Or does not affect it?

Comment: @LoPiTaL I have added an extra reads section, I hope it can clarify your question about copy elision. Thanks for having accepted my answer :)

Comment: @LoPiTaL you can always make the field public and change its type from string to some other type that enforces its own invariance (e.g. via validating constructor or factory method) and is convertible to string. IMHO it's the best way, if the setter is public you're effectively making the field public anyway. Unless the setter is there by convention, e.g. like in QT (which probably is the case here, but if doesn't emit "nameChanged" or similar, my point still stands).

Comment: @alagner Actually, the setter has some logic to allow or not to change the name, and if changed, it emits the nameChanged signal. I understand that having public setters/getters they make the field some sort of "public", but they can introduce some logic, checkers and post-actions (like emit) that otherwhise would have to be done everywhere where the field is set. They introduced encapsulation

Comment: @PicaudVincent thanks for the extra reads section, but there is no information about the return copy ellision optimization. Is it still done when returning const-value?

Comment: @LoPiTaL I have not the answer, sorry. I have to read about that too :)

Comment: @PicaudVincent :) no problem! thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you instead had

```
class Foo
{
public:
    QString & name() {return m_name;}
    const QString & name() const {return m_name;}
    /* optionally also */
    void setName(const QString & name) { m_name = name; }
private:
    QString m_name;
}
```

Then you wouldn't have the problem of modifying prvalues

Comment: Yes, but I want to force to go through the setter, preventing `foo.name().clear()` to succeed. In that case, the name would have changed, but the setter logic would have been bypassed